# Importing owl.carousel in parcel bundler project

Tags: owl-carousel

I am getting the following error while importing owl.carousel in my Parcel bundler project:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
    at owl.carousel.js:1718
    at Object.parcelRequire.node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.js (owl.carousel.js:1755)
    at newRequire (testparcelbundler.e31bb0bc.js:47)
    at localRequire (testparcelbundler.e31bb0bc.js:53)
    at Object.parcelRequire.index.js../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery (index.js:5)
    at newRequire (testparcelbundler.e31bb0bc.js:47)
    at testparcelbundler.e31bb0bc.js:81
    at testparcelbundler.e31bb0bc.js:120
```

My index.js file:

```
// Start import required js
import './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery';
import './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';
import './node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel';
// End import required js

// Start import required css
import './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css';
import './node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
// End import required css
```

What should I do? Been researching on this for two days now..